# iRedMail missing apache2-mod-auth-mysql

Tags: ubuntu, email, email-server

Whenever I try and install iRedMail, it gives me and error saying that apache2-mod-auth-mysql is a missing dependency and I tried installing it but there is no such package

Answer (score 0):

The package apache2-mod-auth-mysql is only available in trusty (14.04): http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apache2-mod-auth-mysql&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all

According to the bug report [1243076](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mod-auth-mysql/+bug/1243076), this won't be fixed. It seems this package is not maintained and not needed anymore. Try to contact the iRedMail developers for a solution.

Also related: [Stackoverflow: Package libapache2-mod-auth-mysql is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458641/package-libapache2-mod-auth-mysql-is-not-available)